# Pass multiple values to single parameter in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Need your help again.

Wanted to know is there any way to pass multiple value to single parameter in SQL Server 2012?

For example,

```
id     item_name  item_code
    1      boots       23
    2       hat        5
    3      dress       11
```

Let's say in the case above, I have parameter `@inp_code`

What to do, so when I will pass '23' and '11' to the parameter so I could get the output below:

```
id      item_name   item_code
   1       boots        23
   3       dress        11
```

Comment: a quick search would reveal table valued parameters...

Comment: how can use it? dont understand(

Comment: how about doing some (any) research? Just a few minutes worth? What did you find when you typed "sql server 2012 table valued parameters" in a search engine???

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

The overall concept is this.

1. You'll create a new table type (listed in SSMS under /Programmability/Types/User-Defined Table Types.  This will
   look like a normal SQL table, except the header is different (CREATE
   TYPE  AS TABLE instead of CREATE TABLE)
2. Once the table type is created, you can define a parameter on your
   stored proc of the table type.
3. In a SQL Script, you define a variable of the table type, INSERT
   into it, and pass it to the stored proc.
4. Inside you stored proc, you can now access the parameter like a
   table (meaning it is a rowset, not a single value, so think
   set-based, not single value)

One item of note - these are not supported via ADO.NET directly.  You would need to create a script that would insert multiple values into the table variable, passing that to the stored proc, and execute the entire script from within your programming language.